# Grails throwing up SVNAuthenticationException on startup (runtime), note i haven't installed svn plugin

Tags: grails

Here are the logs from startup

```
| Compiling 342 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatus
 @ line 19, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatus
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNProperties
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNProperties
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory
 @ line 10, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 16: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient
 @ line 16, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopySource
 @ line 17, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopySource
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDepth
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDepth
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 20: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient
 @ line 20, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl
 @ line 12, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil
 @ line 24, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNNodeKind
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNNodeKind
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusType
 @ line 21, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusType
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory
 @ line 13, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepositoryFactory
 @ line 11, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepositoryFactory
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCommitClient
 @ line 15, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCommitClient
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision
 @ line 18, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient
 @ line 22, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 23: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient
 @ line 23, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNPropertyValue
 @ line 8, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNPropertyValue
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.ISVNStatusHandler
 @ line 14, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.ISVNStatusHandler
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnClient.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL
 @ line 9, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnScmProvider.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil
   ^
C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2\src\groovy\grails\plugin\svn\SvnScmProvider.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException
```

Comment: NOTE : i tried to uninstall the plugin svn and manually delete it from .grails directory, but it is still giving the following error on startup...                              | Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath
Cannot find plugin descriptor for path 'C:\Users\shravan64\.grails\2.1.0\projects\gurujiAatma\plugins\svn-1.0.2'.
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....

Comment: I am having a very similar problem, with the same inability to compile the svn-1.0.2 plugin in a Grails 2.1.0 project. Since it won't compile, one can't uninstall it normally.

Comment: I too am having this issue, have bombed my grails directory and cleaned and still no good...

Comment: Like the OP as well, I can't seem to find where it's being used as a dependency. Not in BuildConfig.groovy, not in application.properties, completely blow away .grails folder, .ivy2 folder, .m2 folder, target folder... Very frustrating

Answer (score 4):

While my colleague and I have still have not discovered the reason this is happening (the Release 1.0.1 and SVN 1.0.2 plugins are being pulled into this app despite no reference in any of the in-house plugins or app itself's `application.properties` or `BuildConfig.groovy`), we have discovered a make-shift solution.

In the failing app's `BuildConfig.groovy`, if you specify

```
build ":release:2.2.1"
```

as a dependency, and you run

```
grails uninstall-plugin svn
```

on your command line, you should be able to stay on Grails 2.1.0 and keep this compilation error from occuring.

I will update my answer here if I'm ever able to find out why the old release plugin was being pulled in as a dependency ( I had bombed my `~/.grails` folder as well as my `~/.ivy2`, so I really have no idea why it was being pulled in ).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this when first building a WAR file containing a reference to a plugin in my company's Grails SVN repository. I fixed it by adding the following to the dependencies section in BuildConfig.groovy, taken from the svn plugin's dependencies:

```
build("org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:1.3.5") {
    excludes "jna", "trilead-ssh2", "sqljet"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  This should be upvoted higher and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the svn 1.0.2 plugin is not working well with grails 2.1.0. Downgrading to grails 2.0.4 seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had checked out the project with svn 1.7 and had the exact same problem.

A friend mentioned svnkit is very sensitive about svn version. I removed the project and checked it out again with svn 1.6 and then it compiled with no issue.

Needless to say, I'll be moving this project to git ASAP. :)